# App doesn't post NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification when finish launching

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter, nsworkspace

My first application listens to NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotifications.  When I launch my second app, it does not trigger the notification in my first app.  Launching any other app does trigger the notification in my first app. I've even tried manually posting the notification in the second app, but it still doesnt work.

Any ideas why the second app may not trigger it?

### First App

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] 
    addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(secondAppDidLaunch:) 
           name:NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification
         object:nil];
```

### Second App

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] 
    postNotificationName:NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification
                  object:self];
```

Comment: How is the second app being launched? Double click in finder?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  My second app had LSUIElement set to 1, which apparently, then will never fire NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotifications.